# Sign an EC2/S3 URL Version 2

Tags: bash, cryptography, url, amazon-web-services

Follow up on previous review:
[Sign an EC2/S3 URL](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/174731/507)

I have fixed the previous comments.
I have also added the code needed to sign HTTP header fields as part of the request.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

url=$1
key=$2
secret=$3

if [[ $# < 3  || $# > 6 ]]; then
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "    sign <url> <key> <secret> [<TimeStamp>] [--headers <fileName>]"
    echo
    echo "Note 1: TimeStamp: must be YYYYMMDD'T'hhmmsa'Z's"
    echo "        eg 20170901T230559Z"
    echo "        YYYY => Year MM => Month DD => day hh => hour mm => minute ss => second"
    echo
    echo "Note 2: Currently does not support URL with Query or Fragment sections."
    exit 1
fi

#
# Pull flags out of the argument list
declare -a ARGS
declare -a PARAM
declare -a PMAP
index=""
for var in "$@"; do
    if [[ "${index}" != "" ]]; then
        PMAP[$index]=${#PARAM[@]}
        PARAM[${#PARAM[@]}]=$var
        index=""
        continue
    fi  
    if [[ "$var" = '--headers' ]]; then
        index=headers
        continue
    fi  
    ARGS[${#ARGS[@]}]="$var"
done

dateTime=${ARGS[3]-$(date -u +"%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")}

#
# Read the list of headers.
# Create the appropriate variables for the HERE Document below
if [[ ${PARAM[headers]} ]]; then
    file=${PARAM[headers]}
    IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a headers < ${file}

    crheaders=()
    headerExtra=""
    prev="host"
    headerList=""
    for loop in "${headers[@]}"; do
        name=$(tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' <<< "${loop%:*}")
        crheaders+=("${name}:${loop#*:}")
        headerExtra+="%3B${name}"
        headerList+=";${name}"

        if [[ "${name}" < "${prev}" ]]; then
            echo "Headers Not in Lexographical Order"
            echo "$name < ${prev}"
            exit 1
        fi
        prev=${name}
    done
fi

#
# The First part of <dateTime> before the T
date=${dateTime%%T*}

#
# Amazon Hosted URLS are built up in sections.
#   http://<service>-<region>.<Amazon End Point><Path>
#
#   Strip out these parts from the url
urlNoSchema=${url#https://}
host=${urlNoSchema%%/*}
serviceRegion=${host%%\.*}
service=${serviceRegion%%-*}
region=${serviceRegion#*-}
path=/${url#https://*/}
file=${path##*/}
expires=3600

#
# Build the canonical request
# Note: If crheaders is empty we get an extra blank line.
#       So run through uniq to remove the blank.
IFS=$'\n'
cr=$((cat - | uniq) <<CanonicalRequest
GET
${path}
X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=${key}%2F${date}%2F${region}%2F${service}%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=${dateTime}&X-Amz-Expires=${expires}&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host${headerExtra}
host:${host}
${crheaders[*]}

host${headerList}
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
CanonicalRequest)

#
# Hash the canonical request
HashedCanonicalRequest=$(echo -n "${cr}" | openssl dgst -sha256)

#
# Build the String to sign.
ss=$(cat - <<StringToSign
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
${dateTime}
${date}/${region}/${service}/aws4_request
${HashedCanonicalRequest}
StringToSign)

#
# Calculate the signature
kDate=$(echo -n ${date}        | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -hmac "AWS4${secret}")
kRegn=$(echo -n ${region}      | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -hmac "${kDate}")
kServ=$(echo -n ${service}     | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -hmac "${kRegn}")
kSign=$(echo -n "aws4_request" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -hmac "${kServ}")
signature=$(echo -n "${ss}"    | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "${kSign}")



#
# Dump intermediate values to compare against language specific implementation.
kDateH=$(echo -n ${date}        | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "AWS4${secret}")
kRegnH=$(echo -n ${region}      | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "${kDate}")
kServH=$(echo -n ${service}     | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "${kRegn}")
kSignH=$(echo -n "aws4_request" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "${kServ}")

cat - <<IntermediateValues
Intermediate Values
url:                      ${url}
key:                      ${key}
secret:                   ${secret}
dateTime:                 ${dateTime}
date:                     ${date}
host:                     ${host}
path:                     ${path}
service:                  ${service}
region:                   ${region}
expires:                  ${expires}
HashedCanonicalRequest:   ${HashedCanonicalRequest}
kDate:                    ${kDateH}
kRegn:                    ${kRegnH}
kServ:                    ${kServH}
kSign:                    ${kSignH}
signature:                ${signature}


Cononical Request:
==================
${cr}

Signing String:
===============
${ss}

Signed URL:
===========
${url}?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=${key}%2F${date}%2F${region}%2F${service}%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=${dateTime}&X-Amz-Expires=${expires}&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host;x-amx-extrastuff;x-amz-stuff&X-Amz-Signature=${signature}


CURL COMMAND:
=============
IntermediateValues

echo -n "curl -o ${file} "
for loop in "${headers[@]}"; do
    echo -n "--header \"${loop}\" "
done

echo "\"${url}?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=${key}%2F${date}%2F${region}%2F${service}%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=${dateTime}&X-Amz-Expires=${expires}&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host;x-amx-extrastuff;x-amz-stuff&X-Amz-Signature=${signature}\""
```

Comment: Follow up: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/174994/507

Answer (score 1):

This can be written a bit simpler:

> ```
> index=""
> for var in "$@"; do
>     if [[ "${index}" != "" ]]; then
>         PMAP[$index]=${#PARAM[@]}
>         PARAM[${#PARAM[@]}]=$var
>         index=""
>         continue
>     fi  
>     if [[ "$var" = '--headers' ]]; then
>         index=headers
>         continue
>     fi  
>     ARGS[${#ARGS[@]}]="$var"
> done
> ```

Like this:

```
index=
for var; do
    if [ "${index}" ]; then
        PMAP[$index]=${#PARAM[@]}
        PARAM+=("$var")
        index=
        continue
    fi  
    if [ "$var" = --headers ]; then
        index=headers
        continue
    fi  
    ARGS+=("$var")
done
```

This too:

> ```
> cr=$((cat - | uniq) <<EOF
> ...
> EOF)
> ```

Like this:

```
cr=$(uniq <<EOF
...
EOF
)
```

Though in this case I get a warning if I don't break the line after the closing `EOF`, and in your version I don't.
I was surprised your version worked at all,
because I thought the here-document must always end with a line containing only the start label and nothing else.
To be honest, as a general practice,
I would not risk it, and just never put anything on the same line.