# S3 Tools in Bash

Tags: bash, s3

This is a follow on to a [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/174994/507):

Part 1: Signature

All the code I am submitting here is available in [github](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/OdinCloud)

> The reason to write these tools is so I can prototype and quickly verify that I am doing things correctly before implementing them in C++. This is mainly necessary because the documentation these scripts are based on are relatively bad and confusing.

s3/signature

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

check=$(echo -n s3 | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:01dda345af12 2> /dev/null | xxd -p -c 256)
if [[ "${check}" != "6d00e194dca4f102300b638bb3404a1c9b8c1ba73514d22a7013f9832c20366a" ]]; then
    echo "Check of openssl failed"
    echo "You need a verions greater than 0"
    exit 1
fi


#
#   method
#   url
#   key
#   secret
#   dateTime        if empty use now utc
#   expires
#   service         if blank extracts from the URL
#   region          if blank extracts from the URL
#   signHeaders     if 1 creates headers for signing otherwise creates query parameters
#   verbose         if blank (empty or just white space) then no extra output.
#                   otherwise it is a filename to output (note - represents stdout)
#   headers[@]

function createSignature {

    local saveIFS=${IFS}

    local method=$1
    local url=$2
    local key=$3
    local secret=$4
    local dateTime=$(echo $5 | xargs)
    local expires=$6
    local service=$7
    local region=$8
    local signHeaders=$9
    local verbose=$(echo ${10} | xargs)
    local headers=("${!11}")

    if [[ "${dateTime}" == "" ]]; then
        dateTime=$(date -u +"%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")
    fi

    #
    # The First part of <dateTime> before the T
    local date=${dateTime%%T*}

    #
    # Amazon Hosted URLS are built up in sections.
    #   http://<service>-<region>.<Amazon End Point><Path>
    #
    #   Strip out these parts from the url
    local urlNoSchema=${url#https://}
    local host=${urlNoSchema%%/*}
    local serviceRegion=${host%%\.*}
    local service=${service-${serviceRegion%%-*}}
    local region=${region-${serviceRegion#*-}}
    local pathAndQueryFrag=/${url#https://*/}
    local pathAndQuery=${pathAndQueryFrag%%#*}
    local path=${pathAndQuery%%\?*}
    local queryItems=${pathAndQuery##*\?}
    if [[ "${queryItems}" == "${pathAndQuery}" ]]; then
        queryItems=""
    fi
    local fragment=${pathAndQueryFrag##*#}
    if [[ "${fragment}" == "${pathAndQueryFrag}" ]]; then
        fragment=""
    else
        fragment="#${fragment}"
    fi
    local file=${path##*/}

    local -a querys
    for loop in $(echo ${queryItems} | sed -e 's/&/ /'); do
        querys+=($loop)
    done

    headers+=("Host:${host}")
    if [[ "${signHeaders}" == "1" ]]; then
        headers+=("X-Amz-Date:${dateTime}")
        headers+=("X-Amz-Content-SHA256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD")
    fi

    local crheaders=()
    local headerExtra=""
    local headerList=""
    for loop in "${headers[@]}"; do
        local name=$(tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' <<< "${loop%:*}")
        crheaders+=("${name}:${loop#*:}")
    done
    IFS=$'\n' sortedHeaders=($(sort <<<"${crheaders[*]}"))
    for loop in "${sortedHeaders[@]}"; do
        local name=${loop%:*}
        headerExtra+="%3B${name}"
        headerList+=";${name}"
    done

    if [[ "${signHeaders}" != "1" ]]; then
        querys+=("X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256")
        querys+=("X-Amz-Credential=${key}%2F${date}%2F${region}%2F${service}%2Faws4_request")
        querys+=("X-Amz-Date=${dateTime}")
        querys+=("X-Amz-Expires=${expires}")
        querys+=("X-Amz-SignedHeaders=${headerExtra#%3B}")
    fi

    IFS=$'\n' sortedQuerys=($(sort <<<"${querys[*]}"))
    local queryParam=""
    local querySep='?'
    for loop in "${sortedQuerys[@]}"; do
        queryParam+="${querySep}${loop}"
        querySep='&'
    done

    #
    # Build the canonical request
    IFS=$'\n'
    cr=$(uniq <<CanonicalRequest
${method}
${path}
${queryParam#?}
${sortedHeaders[*]}

${headerList#;}
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
CanonicalRequest
    )
    IFS=${saveIFS}

    #
    # Hash the canonical request
    local HashedCanonicalRequest=$(echo -n "${cr}" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | xxd -p -c 256)

    #
    # Build the String to sign.
    local ss=$(cat - <<StringToSign
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
${dateTime}
${date}/${region}/${service}/aws4_request
${HashedCanonicalRequest}
StringToSign
    )

    #
    # Calculate the signature
    local kDate=$(echo -n ${date}        | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -hmac "AWS4${secret}" | xxd -p -c 256)
    local kRegn=$(echo -n ${region}      | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -mac HMAC -macopt "hexkey:${kDate}" | xxd -p -c 256)
    local kServ=$(echo -n ${service}     | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -mac HMAC -macopt "hexkey:${kRegn}" | xxd -p -c 256)
    local kSign=$(echo -n "aws4_request" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -mac HMAC -macopt "hexkey:${kServ}" | xxd -p -c 256)
    local signature=$(echo -n "${ss}"    | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -mac HMAC -macopt "hexkey:${kSign}" | xxd -p -c 256)

    if [[ "${verbose}" != "" ]]; then
        cat - <<IntermediateValues > ${verbose}
Intermediate Values
url:                      ${url}
key:                      ${key}
secret:                   ${secret}
dateTime:                 ${dateTime}
date:                     ${date}
host:                     ${host}
path:                     ${path}
service:                  ${service}
region:                   ${region}
expires:                  ${expires}
HashedCanonicalRequest:   ${HashedCanonicalRequest}
kDate:                    ${kDate}
kRegn:                    ${kRegn}
kServ:                    ${kServ}
kSign:                    ${kSign}
signature:                ${signature}


Cononical Request:
==================
${cr}

Signing String:
===============
${ss}

Signed URL:
===========
https://${host}${path}${queryParam}${querySep}X-Amz-Signature=${signature}${fragment}

Headers:
========
IntermediateValues

        printf "%s\n" ${headers[@]}                 >> ${verbose}
        echo                                        >> ${verbose}

        echo "CURL COMMAND:"                        >> ${verbose}
        echo "============="                        >> ${verbose}

        echo -n "curl -o ${file} "                  >> ${verbose}
        for loop in "${headers[@]}"; do
            if [[ ${loop%:*} != "Host" ]]; then
                echo -n "--header \"${loop}\" "     >> ${verbose}
            fi
        done
        if [[ "${signHeaders}" == "1" ]]; then
            echo "--header \"Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=${key}/${date}/${region}/${service}/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=${headerList#;}, Signature=${signature}\" \"https://${host}${path}${queryParam}${fragment}\""   >> ${verbose}
        else
            echo "\"https://${host}${path}${queryParam}${querySep}X-Amz-Signature=${signature}${fragment}\"" >> ${verbose}
        fi
        echo                                        >> ${verbose}
        echo "OUTPUT"                               >> ${verbose}
        echo "======"                               >> ${verbose}
    fi

    if [[ "${signHeaders}" == "1" ]]; then
        echo "Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=${key}/${date}/${region}/${service}/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=${headerList#;}, Signature=${signature}"
    else
        echo "X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=${key}%2F${date}%2F${region}%2F${service}%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=${dateTime}&X-Amz-Expires=${expires}&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=${headerExtra#%3B}&X-Amz-Signature=${signature}"
    fi

}
```