# S3 Bash Tools Part 3

Tags: bash, s3

This is a follow on to a [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/174994/507):

Part 3: User Scripts

All the code I am submitting here is available in [github](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/OdinCloud)

> The reason to write these tools is so I can prototype and quickly verify that I am doing things correctly before implementing them in C++. This is mainly necessary because the documentation these scripts are based on are relatively bad and confusing.

The scripts used by users:

### s3cp

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

badflag=0
declare -a ARGS

function usage {
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "s3cp  <file> <s3-url> [--key=<key>] [--secret=<secret>] [--verbose] [--dryrun]"
    echo "s3cp  <s3-url> <file> [--key=<key>] [--secret=<secret>] [--verbose] [--dryrun]"
    echo
    echo "s3-url:  s3://<bucket>/<Object-Path>"
    exit 1
}

verbose=''
dryrun=0
access=${AMZ_ACCESS_KEY}
secret=${AMZ_SECRET_KEY}
for var in "$@"; do
    if [[ "${var}" == '--verbose' ]]; then
        verbose='/dev/stdout'
        continue
    fi
    if [[ "${var}" == '--dryrun' ]]; then
        dryrun=1
        continue;
    fi
    if [[ "${var%=*}" == "--key" ]]; then
        access=${var#*=}
        continue;
    fi
    if [[ "${var%=*}" == "--secret" ]]; then
        secret=${var#*=}
        continue;
    fi
    flag=${var#-}
    if [[ "${flag}" != ${var} ]]; then
        badflag=1
        echo "Bad flag: ${var}"
        continue
    fi
    ARGS+=("$var")
done

if [[ "${access}" == "" || "${secret}" == "" ]]; then
    echo "Error: No Access or Secret provided."
    echo "These can be set in the environment variables AMZ_ACCESS_KEY/AMZ_SECRET_KEY or passed with flags"
    usage
fi

if [[ ${#ARGS[@]} != 2 || ${badflag} != 0 ]]; then
    usage
fi

src=${ARGS[0]}
dst=${ARGS[1]}

doUpload=0
doDownload=0
srcS3=${src#s3://}
if [[ "${src}" == "${srcS3}" ]]; then
    doUpload=1
fi
dstS3=${dst#s3://}
if [[ "${dst}" == "${dstS3}" ]]; then
    doDownload=1
fi

if [[ ${doUpload} == 0 && ${doDownload} == 0 ]]; then
    echo "Neither source or destination is on S3. Just use normal cp"
    usage
fi
if [[ ${doUpload} == 1 && ${doDownload} == 1 ]]; then
    echo "Both source or destination is on S3. Don't support move yet."
    usage
fi

dir="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"
source ${dir}/s3/signature


if [[ ${doUpload} == 1 ]]; then
    source ${dir}/s3/upload
    upload "${src}" "${dst}" "${access}" "${secret}" '' "${verbose}" "${dryrun}"
else
    source ${dir}/s3/download
    download "${src}" "${dst}" "${access}" "${secret}" '' "${verbose}" "${dryrun}"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

In case of errors/warnings, write your output to `stderr` and not just `echo` them to `stdout` stream. This might also include you returning the `usage` section.

Having a chain of `if` block is imo, always very bad. You can use a `switch-case` block there, and keep `shift`ing the arguments. A simple example would be:

```
ARGS=()
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
    key="$1"

    case $key in
      -v|--verbose)
        verbose='/dev/stdout'
        shift # past argument
        ;;
      --dryrun)
        dryrun=1
        shift # past argument
        ;;
      -k=*|--key=*)
        access="${key#*=}"
        shift # past argument
        shift # past value
        ;;
      -k|--key)
        shift # past argument
        access="$1"
        shift # past value
        ;;
      .
      .
      .
      *)    # unknown option
        if [[ "${key#-}" != ${key} ]]; then
            badflag=1
            >&2 echo "Bad flag: ${var}"
        fi
        ARGS+=("$1") # save it in an array for later
        shift # past argument
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Notice how easily you can maintain the `--key=KEY` and `--key KEY` format parameters. Apart from that, it is really easy to later on add another new argument to your utility.

Keep defining your globals in `UPPER_CASE`, so that it easy to distinguish them later in your ever-expanding code.

> ```
> echo "These can be set in the environment variables AMZ_ACCESS_KEY/AMZ_SECRET_KEY or passed with flags"
> ```

AWS recommends having the environment variables named `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. I would consider it breaking the norm if you are not respecting defaults.

Define the usage content (or man page?) as a heredoc:

```
USAGE=<<EOF

Usage:
s3cp  <file> <s3-url> [--key=<key>] [--secret=<secret>] [--verbose] [--dryrun]
s3cp  <s3-url> <file> [--key=<key>] [--secret=<secret>] [--verbose] [--dryrun]

s3-url:  s3://<bucket>/<Object-Path>

EOF
```